# pcap_next_ex() malloc of pkt_data arg

Tags: c, pcap

Are you supposed to `malloc` the `const u_char **pkt_data` arg to `pcap_next_ex()`?

```
int pcap_next_ex(pcap_t *p, struct pcap_pkthdr **pkt_header, const u_char **pkt_data);
```

i.e.

```
u_char *buf = malloc(100);

pcap_next_ex(pcap_ptr, &pkt_header, &buf);
```

I would have thought not as according to the docs you aren't meant to free `pkt_header` or `buf`:

> The struct pcap_pkthdr and the packet data are not to be freed by the
>   caller, and are not guaranteed to be valid after the next call to
>   pcap_next_ex(), pcap_next(), pcap_loop(), or pcap_dispatch(); if the
>   code needs them to remain valid, it must make a copy of them.

Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: You are not supposed to `malloc` it too. See the example: https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut4.html

Comment: It's a link only.. so nope :)